# pattern matching, tuples and multiplication in Python

Tags: python, pattern-matching, tuples

What is be best way to reduce this series of tuples

```
('x', 0.29, 'a')
('x', 0.04, 'a')
('x', 0.03, 'b')
('x', 0.02, 'b')
('x', 0.01, 'b')
('x', 0.20, 'c')
('x', 0.20, 'c')
('x', 0.10, 'c')
```

into:

```
('x', 0.29 * 0.04 , 'a')
('x', 0.03 * 0.02 * 0.01, 'b')
('x', 0.20 * 0.20 * 0.10, 'c')
```

EDIT:
`X` is a constant, it is known in advance and can be safely ignored

And the data can be treated as pre-sorted on the third element as it appears above.

I am trying to do it at the moment using operator.mul, and a lot of pattern matching, and the odd lambda function... but I'm sure there must be an easier way!

Can I just say thank you for ALL of the answers. Each one of them was fantastic, and more than I could have hoped for. All I can do is give them all an upvote and say thanks!

Comment: Is the first entry of the tuple always `'x'`?  If not, does it matter what it is?

Comment: x is a constant, yes. Im using `(y,z) for (x,y,z)...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a more stateful approach. <sub><sup>(I like @Sven's better.)</sup></sub>

```
def combine(a)
    grouped = defaultdict(lambda: 1)

    for _, value, key in a:
        grouped[key] *= value

    for key, value in grouped.items():
        yield ('x', value, key)
```

This is less efficient if the data are already sorted, since it keeps more in memory than it needs to. Then again, that probably won't matter, because it's not stupidly inefficient either.

Comment: I actually like this one better – except for the use of `_` as a variable name, which is one of my favourite pet oeeves. :)

Comment: I too like this one better. I've picked up my old habit of using `_` again, too, even though I was once taught not to on this very website ;p

Comment: is _ used as a general catch all, (as in Haskell) or is it referencing  the last returned value?

Comment: `'_'` only contains the last returned value within the Python interpreter. In scripts, `'_'` is often used as a placeholder/don't-care value (as I also did in my eerily-similar-but-I-swear-independently-developed answer).

Comment: @PaulMcGuire :) I did do a double take... I still intend to have a play with all of them, so thank you again!

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus: Your question about what `_` means illustrates the main reason you should not use it:  It's just a normal variable name, but confuses many readers of the code wihtout any benefit.  Just use `dummy` or something similar instead.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a functional programming approach:

```py
from itertools import imap, groupby
from operator import itemgetter, mul

def combine(a):
    for (first, last), it in groupby(a, itemgetter(0, 2)):
        yield first, reduce(mul, imap(itemgetter(1), it), 1.0), last
```

Comment: This is lovely. *cough*assuming the data are sorted on the third element*cough*

Comment: `imap(itemgetter(1), it)` is by no means clearer than `(x[1] for x in it)`, IMHO. `itemgetter(0, 2)` is cute, though.

Comment: @katrielalex: Right, I got this impression from the example data, but it should be explicitly stated.

Comment: @larsmans: I just wanted to be consequently "functional".  I'm not really convinced by this code, too. :)

Comment: @larsmans: The usual argument for `itemgetter` is that the loop is then entirely in C. Whether this is meaningful, I don't know.

Comment: @katrielalex: I know, I use `itemgetter` from time to time, but only when refactoring `lambda`-heavy code or as an optimisation. I don't suppose it's that efficient when combined with `imap`, but I'm too lazy to measure.

Comment: Add `a.sort(key=lambda e: e[2])` if necessary.

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi: you must mean `sorted(a, key=itemgetter(2))` ;)

Answer (score 3):

Given that you are ultimately going to multiply together all of the found values, instead of accumulating a list of the values and multiplying them at the end, change your defaultdict to take an initializer method that sets new keys to 1, and then multiply as you go:

```
data = [('x', 0.29, 'a'),
('x', 0.04, 'a'),
('x', 0.03, 'b'),
('x', 0.02, 'b'),
('x', 0.01, 'b'),
('x', 0.20, 'c'),
('x', 0.20, 'c'),
('x', 0.10, 'c'),]

from collections import defaultdict

def reduce_by_key(datalist):

    proddict = defaultdict(lambda : 1)
    for _,factor,key in datalist:
        proddict[key] *= factor

    return [('x', val, key) for key,val in sorted(proddict.items())]

print reduce_by_key(data)
```

Gives:

```
[('x', 0.011599999999999999, 'a'), 
 ('x', 5.9999999999999993e-06, 'b'), 
 ('x', 0.004000000000000001, 'c')]
```